# Why does the "score" column remain 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have very simple code, yet i cannot manage to run it correctly:
It was meant to concat columns, delete duplicates, look up countries in dict and aggregate score, in debugger i can see that below

```
row["score"] += localscore
```

calcualtes correctly, so the issue is with visibility, but I have no clue how to fix it, could any1 help me out?

```
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'countries': ["UK,DE", "DE", "DE"],
                      "other_countries": ["DE", "PL", "PL"]})
scores = {
  "UK": 10.0,
  "DE": 20.0,
  "PL": 30.0
}
my_df["joined_countries_without_duplicates"] = my_df["countries"] + "," + my_df["other_countries"]
my_df["joined_countries_without_duplicates"] = my_df["joined_countries_without_duplicates"].str.split(",")
my_df["score"] = 0
for index, row in my_df.iterrows():
    row["joined_countries_without_duplicates"] = list(set(row["joined_countries_without_duplicates"]))
    localscore = 0
    for country in row["joined_countries_without_duplicates"]:
        localscore += scores[country]
    row["score"] += localscore
```

Comment: You are modifying `row`, but `row` is an entirely different object than your DataFrame, or that row in the DataFrame, so when you modify `row` nothing happens to `my_df`

Answer (score 1):

Changing `row` doesn't change `my_df`.  You'd need to do something like appending `row['score']` to a list and then assign that to `my_df` when you're done.

However this is generally not a good approach.

You could take advantage of [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'countries': ["UK,DE", "DE", "DE"],
                      "other_countries": ["DE", "PL", "PL"]})
scores = {
  "UK": 10.0,
  "DE": 20.0,
  "PL": 30.0
}
my_df["joined_countries_without_duplicates"] = my_df["countries"] + "," + my_df["other_countries"]
my_df["joined_countries_without_duplicates"] = my_df["joined_countries_without_duplicates"].str.split(",").apply(set)

my_df['score'] = (my_df['joined_countries_without_duplicates'].explode()
                                                              .map(scores)
                                                              .groupby(level=0)
                                                              .sum())
```